# ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.62962963'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Basically, I am trying to get the data from CSVs to train the model. Both of the CSVs have more than 1000 rows of data.

My `main.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Data sets
PRES_TRAINING = "file0.csv"
PRES_TEST = "file1.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=PRES_TRAINING,target_dtype=np.int,features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=PRES_TEST,target_dtype=np.int,features_dtype=np.float32)

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=14)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=2,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/tr_model")

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
           y=training_set.target,
           steps=2000)

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
  features_dtype=np.float32)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 51, in load_csv_with_header
  target[i] = np.asarray(row.pop(target_column), dtype=target_dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '2.62962963'
```

I know this is mainly caused by one of the parameters `features_dtype` in `load_csv_with_header()` from Tensorflow. More of it can be read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py).

Given normal situation, I would do a `int(float('2.62962963'))` or something. But I am reading from a large CSV file and this is just one of the single data. And `features_dtype` only takes in a data type, i.e. `np.int`. What other ways can I use to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Either your csv files are static and you can just correct that one mistake by hand (in the file) or the csv files can change and your program needs to be able to handle non-integer values. Then just load the file with floats (or strings if it's really bad) and in the next line convert it like you indicated with `int()`.

Comment: @StefanS It's partly because I am trying to stick to this function, as it gets most of the things done for me than having me to reimplementing it myself. The CSVs are just literally numbers (except column names) with commas when fired up in TextEdit, I guess by static you mean this?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Is the value `2.62962963` an error in the data (should be `2` or `3`) or not? Your sentence "But I am reading from a large CSV file and this is just one of the single data" is not clear to me. You also comment "# Specify that all features have real-value data", which means you don't even want integers. Have you tried `target_dtype=np.float32`?

Comment: @StefanS what I meant was given the number `2.62962963` is just a single data/row&column out of 1000s of them. Well, I have tried using `target_dtype=np.float32` and it would run into compatibility error (because my target is an `int` here, like 0 denotes Product A, 1 denotes Product B).